# d3.timeParse("%Y") : dates 1895 before are not labled correctly

Tags: datetime, d3.js

I have the  problem that years are not labeled correctly in my Bar Chart with Negative Values:

[image]

If I am using dates above 1894 everything works fine, but if i use dates that's like

*"date": "1846"*

the lables are just replaced by *":00"*.

I am using d3.v4.min.js. Data comes from a simple JSON. 
This example is used as a basis: https://bl.ocks.org/WillTurman/9c4142944f6132855fd318350f552b7b

How can I change this

```
    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");
```

so it also labels years below 1895?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem using the linked example and pre 1894 dates: [demo](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/84c4bddd8b24a8f2a5ec7999d5c6c7b8). Is it possible to share some code and data that replicates the problem?

Comment: it just came into my mind to try out another browser and it seems that it is not working for chrome?  but its actually wirking with firefox. ^^

Comment: so is it possible thats there is a problem with chrome or maybe its just my machine + Chrome?

Comment: I often try different browsers when I have trouble replicating questions, but I didn't think this was a question where that would matter - but yep, chrome for me produces the bad date formatting for me too. I had originally just tried firefox. I'll take another look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code appears to work in Firefox, but not Chrome (v68). I haven't checked other browsers, in any event, there is a problem.

The issue is in the axis, dates are otherwise handled appropriately: the graph is displayed as it should be. Specifically, the issue is in the default axis tick format function - after all the axis is created properly too - only the tick labels are in the wrong format.

For whichever reason (I haven't dug into it yet), the default tick format behavior appears to differ between Firefox and Chrome with respect to the dates and axis you are using. This can be solved by specifying your own tick format:

```
var timeFormat = d3.timeFormat("%Y"); 

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
   .tickFormat(timeFormat)
```

This should give you something like:

```js
var width = 600, height = 200;
var start = "January 1, 1600";
var end = "January 1, 2000";

var parse = d3.timeParse("%B %d, %Y");
var format = d3.timeFormat("%Y");

var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([parse(start),parse(end)])
  .range([10,width-10]);
  
var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(format);

d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
   .attr("width",width)
   .attr("height",height)
   .append("g")
   .attr("transform","translate(0,100)")
   .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

And here's an [example](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/f58edccee5aa72bf1cbe90b5c40fe3f9) using your example.

*If you want to format the date differently (I'm using just the year in this example), take a look at d3's time formatting specifiers [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format).*