# How to render dates on x axis prior to 1900 with d3 .js scatter plot

Tags: date, d3.js

My d3 scatter plot uses historic date data in a range from 1600 to present. I can plot my dots successfully but can't display the dates prior to 1900 I the x axis.

I am using this [example to make a scatterplot in d3](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/bubble_basic.html) but my data has historic dates prior to 1900. I have tried to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057498/d3-timeparsey-dates-1895-before-are-not-labled-correctly) but this returns a single date repeated for each tick mark

If I try to implement d3.axisBottom(x) this returns the dates from my data, but dates prior to 1900 are not formatted correctly.

I have made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jt722pXq36JRNcIEpbkB) with full code

Here is my relevant scale and axis code (from the plunkr):

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(10).tickFormat(function(d){return timeFormat(d);});
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10);

var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return (d.dates);}))
  .range([ 0, width ]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  //.call(xAxis, function (d){return (d);});
  //.call(xAxis, function (d){return (d.dates);}); // returns just a single date for all tick marks
 .call(d3.axisBottom(x)); // partially correct dates but not formatting dates prior to 1900
```

My scatter plot is fine and the dots are as expected. What I want to see on the x axis is the dates prior to 1900, eg 1750.

Very grateful for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The referenced answer is correct, you have other issues in your code. *I've also updated that answer a bit to clean the code and include a generic example with an axis from 1600-2000.*

The first problem is that you define your x scale:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
```

Then pretty much immediately define your axis:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(timeFormat);
```

Then you define the x domain, while redefining x as well with:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return (d.dates);}))
  .range([ 0, width ]);
```

If we use `svg.call(xAxis)`, this means that the axis is using the first x scales domain, which defaults to  [January 1 2000, January 2 2000], which is why every tick will have the same year if you apply the axis with only a default domain.

*Your code has `.call(d3.axisBottom(x)` rather than `.call(xAxis)`, which creates a new axis again, but without the formatting needed to render pre 1900 dates*

Instead, determine the scale's domain first, then create the axis:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {return (d.dates);}))

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat(timeFormat);
```

And now you can just apply the axis:

```
selection
  .attr("transform",...)
  .call(xAxis);
```

Here's an updated [plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/j2Pfhc5HujQRKCq0)